# Describing a field (data dictionary not statistics)

Tags: splunk

Brand new to Splunk and curious whether there is a way to add descriptive text to the pop out window that appears when a user selects (clicks) a field in the search results?  I am building a data dictionary for myself, but I would like to view these descriptions in Splunk.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Not as such - unless you "intelligently" name the fields (or field aliases) or eventtypes, you're going to get whatever the field name is, and whatever the field's contents are